# How to implement group list inside another group list (groupby). Is it possible to use multiple hashcode and operator== in a dart custom object

Tags: flutter, dart, group-by, equals, hashcode

```
class People  {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String name;
  final String location;
  final String email;
  final String lga;
 

  People({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.location,
    this.email,
    this.lga,
    
  });


  factory People.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => People(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    name: json["name"],
    location: json["location"],    
    email: json["email"],
    lga: json["lga"],
   

  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "name": name,
    "location": location,    
    "email": email,
    "lga": lga,
   
  };


@override
  bool operator ==(o) =>
    o is Priest && townOrigin == o.townOrigin && lga == o.lga;

@override
  int get hashCode => town.hashcode ^ lga.hashcode;
```

This is possible in a listView between town or lga but my problem is, I want to implement these equals and `hashCode` in locations too, differently in another ListView.

To make it simple, many people have the same location but I only need one location, from many (as a header) of people from the same location and iterate their names below.

Any help?

```
[
  {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Ada Kenneth Kenechukwu",
      "location": "Awka",
      "townOrigin": "Nimo",
      "phone": "080633",
       "lga": "Njikoka",
      
  },
{
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Ugo John",
      "location": "Awka",
      "townOrigin": "Nimo",
      "phone": "08057763",
      "lga": "Njikoka",
     
  },
{
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Okafor Kenneth Kenechukwu",
      "location": "Awka",
      "townOrigin": "Ukpo",
      "phone": "0806363",
      "lga": "Dunukofia",
      
  },
{
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Ndu Agi",
      "location": "Awka",
      "townOrigin": "Ukpo",
      "phone": "0806763",
      "lga": "Dunukofia",
     
  },
 {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Mma Peter",
      "location": "Awka",
      "townOrigin": "Ichida",
      "phone": "08057763",
       "lga": "Anaocha",
      
  },
{
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Eze Peter",
      "location": "Awka",
      "townOrigin": "Ichida",
      "phone": "0806345",
       "lga": "Anaocha",
     
  }
]
```

When you look at this, some have the same location, townOrigin,lga. I have three listView pages in my app where it will display all those(names) from the same location,townOrigin,lga alone respectively . Displaying only names but using one element(like Awka in location) as a subhead.The same applies to all townOrigin, and lga. Looking forward for help.

I have gotten something better, but yet to solve all my issues,
with this package sticky_grouped_list, https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_grouped_list

I wanted a group inside a group. I have gotten a group of lga but yet in location inside lga group.
[image]

How to merge people from the same location like "Uga" into one.

Comment: You haven't explained why you need `operator ==` and `hashCode` at all.  If you're using these objects in a `Map` or `Set`, you can construct a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html) or a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html) and explicitly provide different equality and hash code callbacks in their constructors.

Comment: @jamesdlin, I'm using it to select one element from many elements of the same name.

Comment: I have edited above for clarity.

Comment: I still don't understand.  `ListView` just displays a list of widgets.  It doesn't care about element equality.  The only reason you'd need `hashCode` is if you're *hashing* objects, which would happen if you store them in a hashing collection (e.g. `Map`/`LinkedHashMap` or `Set`/`LinkedHashSet`).  Exactly what will be calling `operator ==` and `hashCode`?

Comment: Ok may be I'm making wrong use of hashcode and operator. Need help. Thanks for your kindness. Now, how can I get only one data element from repeated(same) data elements like stipulated above example. Recheck the json and see some repeated strings in users, like their location,lga.  Forget about the ListView now, its for display of the element.

Comment: I still don't understand.  If you want to select an item from a collection, iterate over the items in that collection and find the one you want by whatever means you want.  For example: `items.where((item) => item.location == 'Awka)`.

Comment: Still on this issue.

Comment: Still on this issue. This  items.where((item) => item.location == 'Awka) will give all location in Awka, may be up to 300.But I just need one item.location as a caption ,then display their names (grouping). Secondly, new user location can be added in the database, the above code may not help out, it will only display the hard coded ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding something like this:

```
extension GroupingBy on Iterable<dynamic> {
  Map<String, List<dynamic>> groupingBy(String key){
    var result = <String, List<dynamic>>{};
    for(var element in this){
      result[element[key]] = (result[element[key]] ?? [])..add(element);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

This will let you group your data elements by a particular field.

First, put your data into a list:

```
var people = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Ada Kenneth Kenechukwu",
        "location": "Awka",
        "townOrigin": "Nimo",
        "phone": "080633",
        "lga": "Njikoka",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ugo John",
        "location": "Awka",
        "townOrigin": "Nimo",
        "phone": "08057763",
        "lga": "Njikoka",
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Okafor Kenneth Kenechukwu",
        "location": "Awka",
        "townOrigin": "Ukpo",
        "phone": "0806363",
        "lga": "Dunukofia",
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Ndu Agi",
        "location": "Awka",
        "townOrigin": "Ukpo",
        "phone": "0806763",
        "lga": "Dunukofia",
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Mma Peter",
        "location": "Awka",
        "townOrigin": "Ichida",
        "phone": "08057763",
        "lga": "Anaocha",
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Eze Peter",
        "location": "Awka",
        "townOrigin": "Ichida",
        "phone": "0806345",
        "lga": "Anaocha",
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "New Person",
        "location": "Somewhere else",
        "townOrigin": "idk",
        "phone": "694201738",
        "lga": "Mystery",
      }
    ];
```

Now, if you want to group them by location, you can do that simply, like so:

```
var peopleByLocation = people.groupingBy('location');
var awka = peopleByLocation['Awka']; //List of all people with a 'location' : 'Awka'
var somewhereElse = peopleByLocation['Somewhere else'];
```

Here's a link to a slightly modified version in dartpad that you can play around with: https://dartpad.dev/8a53fc2eb4f63d904f414ea528574baf

Comment: Please explain more to these. I have decoded my json data. I am using custom object like specified above. Thanks

Comment: You don't want to use multiple equals/hashcode implementations for this. Also you can't. What you want to do, is take the list of all the people, and then group them based on a particular field. Like location. The last 3 lines of code I posted above, the first line groups the people into lists based on their locations.

Comment: I have tried similar something with dart extension (groupBy).  List<People> _pp=[ ];   List<People> get ppl{ _pp.groupBy((p) => p.townOrigin); }. I got this error => A value of type 'Map<dynamic, List<dynamic>>' can't be returned from function 'ppl' because it has a return type of 'List<People>'. I want to return it as a list not a map. Thanks

Comment: Yes. First create the map. Then use the location you want the people from to get the list of people out. You create the Map<Location, List<People>>, then, Map['awka'] will be the list of people from that location. Exactly like the last 3 lines I posted. The first line creates the map. The second line get's the list of people from 'Awka' out of the map. The 3rd line gets the list of people from 'Somewhere else' out of the map.

Comment: I'm adding a link to a dartpad so you can see and play around with the code

Comment: This is great @loganrussell48. Exactly what I'm looking for. But the issue left is how to implement it in my ListView.builder() widget. Thanks greatly as I wait for your reply.

Comment: With such small number of elements in the list, I would say it's ok to just pass the standard ListView widget the list of people. The ListView.builder is better when your list starts to become large, or infinite, in size

Comment: The list is big. The one you saw is a sample list. It's about 3000 persons stored in api json file. Thanks in anticipation.